# Mutiple Dags execution with single scheduler with LocalExecutor

Tags: airflow

Assuming I am running Single Scheduler with LocalExecutor. So, I have one worker. With this setting, Can I run multiple DAGs at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [LocalExecutor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/local.html) can run multiple tasks at the same time (thus multiple DAGs). The degree of concurrency is configurable by setting core.parallelism in your airflow.cfg.

Comment: Well I can imagine Local executor spinning multiple process for multiple tasks in A DAG. How does this varies with multiple DAGS? Also, Local Executor can have just one worker or many?

Comment: LocalExecutor does not have "worker" concept. LocalExecutor as described in the docs spawns process that are processing the tasks (the numbe of them is configurable with core.parallelism value). Executor have no notion of DAG, so yes, LocalExecutor will work with multiple DAGs and it's quite common to use it on small, single machine deployments.